# grayt_autoStartup = true,

Tags: ckeditor, scayt

According to http://www.webspellchecker.net/samples/grayt-ckeditor-plugin.html 
the statement  CKEDITOR.config.grayt_autoStartup = true; should activate "GrammarAsYouType (GRAYT) for CKEditor 4+" grammer service on the editor
Their demo code did not even show the spelling button on my local test.
The code from http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/spellchecker.html did show the spelling options but not grammer.
Tried to add to the config:"grayt_autoStartup = true," like the "scayt_autoStartup: true," works, but then the entire UI was gone and no spell or grammar check.

Any one has a spelling AND grammar working in a local deployment?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are right - GRAYT for CKEditor can be started like this:

```
grayt_autoStartup: true
```

For adding spelling button to CKEditor UI you need the following:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [{
    name: 'editing',
    items: ['Scayt']
}];
```

There is no separate button for GRAYT. So you will have button only for SCAYT.

- jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jalners/j4ytgb2v/